# hidden object flash game

Tags: android, flash, object, hidden

I am making a hidden object game for my class. Now I'm doing this on the air android so I can see the game on my phone. I am have no clue of what kind of code I need to have to link my objects to a list of the names of the objects and when you find that object that list name will get marked out or something. And possibly wanting to do a hint for my game. And a scoring system when objects are found, I've done a little but I got stuck. I have found a example of a game that I was trying to follow but, I don't know where to find these kinds of elements to do on my game. [seek and find game tutorial](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?736571-seek-and-find-game-tutorial). If you go done to the fourth post that is where the example game is. I can show you what I have so far in my game, but its really not much..

I have set up a var myname in the objects itself so it reads `var myname="Magician Hat";`

```
import flash.events.Event;

//hitting objects to disappear
var Hits:int = 0;

object0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object12.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);
object13.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hiddenObject);

function hiddenObject(e:Event):void {
    e.target.visible = false;
    Hits++
}

//timer
var mytimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,30);

mytimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandle);
function timerHandle(event:TimerEvent):void {
    myText.text = 31- mytimer.currentCount + "";
}

mytimer.start();

//scoring
var score:Number = 0;

function changeScore(num:Number):void {
    MovieClip(root).score += num;
    MovieClip(root).score_txt.text = String(MovieClip(root).score);
}

stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I done some normal Actionscript 3.0 for my mobile application fortunately you only have to deploy it to apk that's all. Hope it helps.